# Jquery progress bar arr

Tags: jquery, html, progress-bar

I want to make a prog bar like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4EIO.jpg), I want the prog bar to be an arr and built it from js file and not in the index.html

```
 $progAdd = $('<div>', {
    'id': 'proggg'
});

var progress = [
    {
        name: 'aaaa',
        value:50px
    },
    {
        name: 'bbbb',
        value:20px
    }
];

    for(i in progress) {
    var $tempProg = $('<li>');

    $tempProg.append('<div id="progressbar" style="width:100px;"></div>');
            $( function() {
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: progress[i].value
}); 
    $progAdd.append($tempProg);
}
$progAdd.appendTo('#pro-skills');
```

my index.html code

```
  <section id="pro-skills">
   <h1 class="ex-title">pro skills</h1>
   </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you getting any errors you can share?

since you are using the Object to set the value, you should change `50px` to `50` (50px is not valid value anyway since it's a string and should have quetes around it) value should be a number http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#option-value

also - you are creating multiple `#progressbar` so that will create problems here:

```
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: progress[i].value
});
```

you should not reuse id's (ever) and you set the progressbar to the object like

```
var $progBar = $('<div>');
$progBar.progressbar({
  value: progress[i].value
});
```

another issue - `$tempProg` is a div and you are appending `<li>` to it (`<li>` should sit inside `<ul>` or `<ol>` etc)

so try:

```
var $progAdd = $('<ul>', {
    'id': 'proggg'
});

var progress = [
    {
        name: 'aaaa',
        value:50
    },
    {
        name: 'bbbb',
        value:20
    }
];
for(i in progress) {
    var $tempProg = $('<li>');
    var $progBar = $('<div>').width(100);
    $tempProg.append($progBar);
    $( function() {
        $progBar.progressbar({
             value: progress[i].value
        }); 
        $progAdd.append($tempProg);
    });
}
$progAdd.appendTo('#pro-skills');
```